# Yii2 composer update (install) eats all memory

Tags: yii2, composer-php

When I trying to update composer in project i have a problem with memory limit and can't update it.

I have tried to install composer globally and locally but it same.
The fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0 was installed globally.

If -d memory_limit = -1 it eat all RAM memory and freezes,
if I set memory_limit to 2GB or 4GB I just get memory limit error,

I have this problem on 3 different Yii2 projects and on a different PC
(MacOS, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04). Right now I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.

Here is composer.json one of my projects:

```
{
  "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
  "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Application Template",
  "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "application template"],
  "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "*",
    "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta",
    "bower-asset/admin-lte": "~1.0",
    "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.*",
    "bower-asset/font-awesome": "~4.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-icons": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
    "kop/yii2-scroll-pager": "dev-master",
    "nirvana-msu/yii2-infinite-scroll": "1.0.*@dev",
    "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0",
    "bower-asset/angular": "*",
    "bower-asset/angular-route": "*",
    "bower-asset/angular-strap": "*",
    "2amigos/yii2-chartjs-widget" : "~2.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "dev-master",
    "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "^2.0",
    "2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget": "~1.1",
    "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget": "~1.0",
    "kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput": "@dev",
    "shiyang/yii2-masonry": "*",
    "shiyang/yii2-infinite-scroll": "*",
    "bower-asset/masonry": "~3.2",
    "bower-asset/imagesloaded": "*",
    "bower-asset/eventemitter": "4.*",
    "2amigos/yii2-gallery-widget": "~1.0",
    "philippfrenzel/yii2masonry": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
    "2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget": "~1.0",
    "newerton/yii2-fancybox": "dev-master",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "^5.1",
    "kartik-v/yii2-sortable": "*",
    "serhatozles/yii2-simplehtmldom": "dev-master",
    "mailgun/mailgun-php": "~1.7.2",
    "geoip2/geoip2": "~2.0",
    "bower-asset/clipboard": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
  },
  "extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
      "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
      "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    },
      "asset-repositories": [
          {
              "name": "bower-asset/eventemitter",
              "type": "bower-vcs",
              "url": "git://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter.git"
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Some of those seem redundant. Are you sure you need `"fxp/composer-asset-plugin"` here? Also isn't `dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset` already calling for `bower-asset/admin-lte`. Remove the fxp one, try again and if the problem persists remove all not default, update and then add them one by one updating after each so you can see which one is eating memory.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I was hoping that there is some method without checking packages one by one, I will try to do that

Comment: Problem was solved by adding to composer.json extra: 
"asset-pattern-skip-version": "(-patch)",
    "asset-vcs-driver-options": {
      "github-no-api": true
    },